# executing two similar javascript in one page?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying use two similar javascript in one page, I already differentiate their id name but when I run my app it's always the first declared script that will only work while the second one doesn't. 
Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                // Radialize the colors
                Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                    return {
                        radialGradient: {cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7},
                        stops: [
                            [0, color],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                        ]
                    };
                });

                // Build the chart
                $('#view2').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Persentasi Jumlah Guru Laki Laki Dan Perempuan'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                },
                                connectorColor: 'silver'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                            type: 'pie',
                            name: 'Persentase',
                            data: [['Perempuan', 70],
                                ['Laki -Laki', 30]



                            ]
                        }]
                });
            });
        </script>;
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                // Radialize the colors
                Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                    return {
                        radialGradient: {cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7},
                        stops: [
                            [0, color],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                        ]
                    };
                });

                // Build the chart
                $('#view1').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Persentasi Jumlah Guru Laki Laki Dan Perempuan'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                },
                                connectorColor: 'silver'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                            type: 'pie',
                            name: 'Persentas',
                            data: [['Perempuan', 50],
                                ['Laki -Laki', 50]



                            ]
                        }]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The code above will only execute the first declared script (#view2) while the second one (#view1) doesn't work. I have no idea what is the problem, and if you can help please and thank you.

For more details, I'm trying to call them within the same page like :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span6">
                            <div id="view1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span6">
                            <div id="view2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/span-->
```

Comment: what is the error in above code?

Comment: @nmnsud there's no error but when I try to call the the second script with id `view1` it's just doesn't work while the first one with id `view2` will work just fine

Comment: The difference I see is in the name attribute under Series one says, "Persentase" while the other says "Persentas"

Comment: @sjramsay The first script has id `$('#view2').highcharts` while the second one is `$('#view1').highcharts`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this code out of the second script:

// Radialize the colors

```
            Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                return {
                    radialGradient: {cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7},
                    stops: [
                        [0, color],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                    ]
                };
            });
```

Also, you have ";" after the first closing script tag which will cause it to show up on the page.

Also you can take you #view1 code and put in inside the same script block as #view2 to make it more compact.